# My custom scaling method not working

Tags: java, c++, opengl

I've got the following code to display an image/texture in Opengl. The method is supposed to display the image in its correct aspect ratio and zoom in/out.

The image does not seem to maintain its aspect ratio on the horizontal axis. Why?

*(NB: The OpenGL viewing width is from -1 to 0 and height from 1 to -1).*

```
private void renderImage(Rectangle dst, float magnification) {
        float width, height;
        float horizontalOffset, verticalOffset;

        // Default: Fill screen horizontally
        width = 1f;
        height = dst.getHeight()/(float) dst.getWidth();


        // magnification
        width *= magnification;
        height *= magnification;

        // Offsets
        horizontalOffset = width/2f;
        verticalOffset = height/2f;

        // Do the actual OpenGL rendering
        glBegin (GL_QUADS);
        // Right top
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f + horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);

        // Right bottom
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f + horizontalOffset, -verticalOffset);

        // Left bottom
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f - horizontalOffset, -verticalOffset);

        // Left top
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f - horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
        glEnd();

    }
```

Comment: I think you need to take the aspect ratio of the viewing area into account. If the viewing width is from -1 to 0 and height from 1 to -1, then this computation will only work if the viewing area is twice as high as it is wide.

Comment: I've set verticalOffset = verticalOffset * 2; The result is more pleasing, however not perfect. I'm guessing you are right though.

Comment: Instead of simply multiplying by 2, try `verticalOffset *= 2.0 * screen_width / screen_height;`, where screen_width and screen_height are the size in pixels of the area you draw into.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with OpenGL but from looking at your code it seems that there is something fishy about your default fill.

```
// Default: Fill screen horizontally
width = 1f;
height = dst.getHeight()/(float) dst.getWidth();
```

This is setting your "width" variable to a constant value of 1 whilst the "height" variable relies on the height and width of the rectangle that you are passing in, which is then being used to calculate the offsets

```
// Offsets
horizontalOffset = width/2f;
verticalOffset = height/2f;
```

in my experience this can cause the problems you have stated, first try stepping through this function in the debugger to analyse the values that the width and height variables hold, or try changing

```
// Default: Fill screen horizontally
width = 1f;
height = dst.getHeight()/(float) dst.getWidth();
```

to

```
// Default: Fill screen horizontally
width = 1f;
height = 1f;
```

and rerun this to see if it has had an effect on your output